# Is it possible to use the Swipe Gesture Recognizer in a PFImageView?

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform, uiswipegesturerecognizer

As the question states, is it possible to use the Swipe Gesture Recognizer in a PFImageView?

I have a PFQueryTableViewController with a cell that segues to a PFImageView which I want to load with more than 1 image.. I do not know how to retrieve the information, could this be done?

Much help appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: Yes, But I don't know how to load the files from Parse.com. Do you know where I could find a tutorial or sample related to this?

Comment: I am not familiar with Parse SDK, but your question is asking something different. Edit your question to ask the correct thing

Comment: Thanks! I changed it, hope this gets me to some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A gesture recognizer can be added to any view, and PFImageView inherits from UIView (ultimately), so yes, it is possible :-)